# Adding to a div after jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has data in it and when you click on certain items a jquery ui dialog box appears to make sure you want to add that specific item. My question is how do I actually add the item (just the item name) that was clicked on after they hit yes on the dialog box?

my html is just a table (it has to be a table) with a button on the left side and then the name in the second column and information in the third column so

```
<tr>
    <td><button class="itemButton"></td>
    <td> item1 </td>
    <td> description </td>
</tr>
```

and I want to add it to a div called cart

```
<div id="cart"></div>
```

here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dialogDiv = $('#dialog');

    $('.itemButton').click(function () {
        dialogDiv.dialog('open');
    });

     dialogDiv.dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
            'Add': function () {
                 HELP HERE!!!!!!
                 dialogDiv.dialog('close');
             },
            'Cancel': function (){
                dialogDiv.dialog('close');
          }
      }
   });
});
```

for the other ones that don't need a pop up i have this for my jquery

```
$('.add').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().clone().appendTo('p').after('<br>');
});
```

and that works fine.

thank you.

Comment: You are looking for the `append` or `appendTo` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you would want to move the entire row in the cart with the button and all so here's an answer for adding a DIV with just the item's info in the cart. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5997mh8/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dialogDiv = $('#dialog'),
    itemName = '';

    $('.itemButton').click(function () {
        dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        itemName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    });

     dialogDiv.dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
            'Add': function () {
                $('<div>' + itemName + '</div>').appendTo('#cart');
                 dialogDiv.dialog('close');
             },
            'Cancel': function (){
                dialogDiv.dialog('close');
          }
      }
    });
});
```

You also need to fix the markup for that button. It is missing it's closing tag

```
<button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: Sorry I will edit. I don't want to add the entire row just the item name!

Comment: Edited my answer for just the item name.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `mark` the button clicked with a class, and use that class to move the correct row to the `cart` when confirmed.

**This example leaves the `Add Button` when added to the cart for expediency.**

Edit:  update to move only the item name [Cell 2]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dialogDiv = $('#dialog');

  $('.itemButton').click(function() {
    $('.itemButton.debating').removeClass("debating"); //remove any old marker
    $(this).addClass("debating"); //mark this button
    dialogDiv.dialog('open');
  });

  dialogDiv.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      'Add': function() {
        $("<div>").text($('.itemButton.debating').closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text()).appendTo($("#cart")); //move the marked text
        dialogDiv.dialog('close');
      },
      'Cancel': function() {
        dialogDiv.dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link type='text/css' href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id='dialog'>Are you sure?</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="itemButton">Add</button></td>
    <td> item1 </td>
    <td> description </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="itemButton">Add</button></td>
    <td> item2 </td>
    <td> description 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="itemButton">Add</button></td>
    <td> item3 </td>
    <td> description 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="cart" style='background-color: red;'></div>
```